# ServiceStack.Net OrmLite Adding Autoincrement to table id without using an attribute

Tags: c#, orm, attributes, ormlite-servicestack

I am creating a Dal using OrmLite for persisting Models from a library which does not (and should not) have Orm-specific attributes on it's class properties.

When I create tables based on these classes with OrmLite, is it possible, without these attributes, to specify Autoincrement for the Id (and/or other such things which can be defined by attributes)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and could not find any way other than using attributes to get my autoincrement ID. Since ServiceStack.ORMlite is open source you can however easily adapt the code according to your own needs. I ended up moving all the attributes into a separate library project. If you do not want to use attributes at all you could also introduce some kind of additional naming convention like it is done for Id/PrimaryKey or just make any ID AutoIncrement.